# Common maven repository for GitLab CI

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I hope someone can help me with a simple setup of maven CI scripts for GitLab.

I tried to search stackoverflow and google, which results in several questions and answers, but either they seem to be completely different or not that I understand them.

I have a simple setup of two projects. `project B` depends on `project A` (= pom packaging).

I have in the runner configuration `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` the line with the volumes added

```
[[runners]]
...
  [runners.docker]
  ...
   volumes = ["/cache", "/.m2"]
  ...
```

my `.gitlab-ci.yml` for both projects look like this

```
image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-12

cache:
  paths:
    - /.m2/repository
    - target/

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=/.m2/repository"

maven_job:
  script:
    - mvn clean install
```

with this - the first project builds correctly and I can see that the caching is working, as it does not download all maven related plugins for building the project, when executed again and again.

It also states

`[INFO] Installing /builds/end2end/projectA/pom.xml to /.m2/repository/de/end2end/projectA/0.4.4-SNAPSHOT/projectA-0.4.4-SNAPSHOT.pom`

It reports though at the end

```
WARNING: /.m2/repository: not supported: outside build directory 
WARNING: /.m2/repository/classworlds: not supported: outside build directory 
WARNING: /.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds: not supported: outside build directory 
WARNING: /.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2: not supported: outside build directory 
WARNING: /.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/_remote.repositories: not supported: outside build directory 
[...]
```

When executing `projectB`, the job fails with the info, that it cannot find `projectA`.

So - what is wrong with the configuration of the runner / .gitlab-ci.yml files ?

I tried

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
```

which removes the warnings, but then the projectA gets in its local `.m2` installed

`[INFO] Installing /builds/end2end/projectA/pom.xml to /builds/end2end/projectAt/.m2/repository/de/end2end/projectA/0.4.4-SNAPSHOT/projectA-0.4.4-SNAPSHOT.pom`

and `projectB` fails with the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as described in [gitlab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-persistent-storage), you use the `dynamic storage` so the volume is shared between subsequent runs of the same concurrent job for one project. I you want to share data between projects you must use `the host-bound storage`.

For the warning, the cache is only for working directory, so absolute path like `/.m2/repository` is not supported. In your case, you don't have to use cache for maven repository because you use a volume.